# ordering in np.nditer for order='C' and flags=['external_loop']

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

I'm working through the Numpy [tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html#using-an-external-loop) and I have the following question.

If we do

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
```

Then

```
a=array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

If we iterate over the array in Fortran order using

```
for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='F'):
    print(x,end=' ')
```

The output is

```
[0 3] [1 4] [2 5]
```

which makes sense. But if we iterate in `C` order using

```
for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='C'):
    print(x,end=' ')
```

the output is

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

which I cannot explain. I would have expected the output to be

```
[0 1 2] [3 4 5]
```

Is Numpy combining [0 1 2] and [3 4 5] because they are stored contiguously in memory?

Comment: yes, the data buffer for an array is one contiguous c` array.

Comment: `nditer` is mainly of value if you go on to use in c or cython code. I haven't seen evidence of it improving performance in python code.  So don't spend too much time trying to master it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [python doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer):
*Observe that with the default of keeping native memory order, the iterator is able to provide a single one-dimensional chunk, whereas when forcing Fortran order, it has to provide three chunks of two elements each.*

To better understand the importance of order of your array check out this example:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
#by default `a` is of order `C`

for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='F'):
    print(x,end=' ')
#[0 3] [1 4] [2 5] 
for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='C'):
    print(x,end=' ')
#[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Now, we change the order of `a` to `F` and see what happens:

```
a = np.array(a,order='F')

for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='F'):
    print(x,end=' ')
#[0 3 1 4 2 5] 
for x in np.nditer(a,flags=['external_loop'],order='C'):
    print(x,end=' ')
#[0 1 2] [3 4 5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That clears up things a bit. The order in which the original array was stored clearly matters.

Comment: @NachiketGokhale That is exactly what the tutorial says. As long as your order in nditer is the same as native order of the array, it will provide single 1-D array of elements. If the order of nditer is different than order of array, then it will return chunks of 1-D each.